# onclick event on working and sometimes conflict between two table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

i am currently working with html table,but my table onclick event is conflict between two table.two table is located in different pages.but i dont know why they conflict and sometimes they are even not working.

my html and js code(1st page)----------

```
<table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Picture Path</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Heading</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Adding Date</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Body</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">Add A Course</th>
</tr>
<?php

mysql_connect("host", "user", "")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
    mysql_select_db("databse name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "select * from somewhere";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         echo '<tr>
         <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["pic_path"].'</div></td>             
         <td><div onclick="getval(this)" class="cventablehead" id="ventablehead" style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll; cursor: pointer; color:red;">'.$row["heading"].'</div></td>
         <td>'.$row["adding_date"].'</td>
         <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["body"].'</div></td>
         <td><button onclick="idna(this)">Add</button></td>
         </tr>';
    }
?>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function idna(el){
      var rownumber = $(el).closest('tr').index();
         alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[rownumber].cells[1].textContent);
    }
  </script>
```

my second table html and js code(2nd page)------------

```
 <table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th style="width:14.28%;">Vendor Name</th>
  <th style="width:14.28%;">Course Picture Path</th>
  <th style="width:14.28%;">Course Name</th>
  <th style="width:14.28%;">Course Code</th>
  <th style="width:14.28%;">Course Adding Date</th>
  <th style="width:14.28%;">course Details</th>
  <th style="width:14.28%;">Add A Batch</th>
</tr>
<?php

    mysql_connect("host", "user", "")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
    mysql_select_db("database name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "select * from somewhere";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         echo '<tr>
         <td id="co1"><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["vendor_heading"].'</div></td>
        <td id="co2"><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["pic_path"].'</div></td>          
         <td><div onclick="coursename(this)" id="co3" style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll; cursor: pointer; color:red;">'.$row["name"].'</div></td>
        <td id="co4"><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["code"].'</div></td> 
        <td id="co5"><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["adding_date"].'</div></td>
         <td id="co6"><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["details"].'</div></td>
         <td><button onclick="idna1(this)">Add</button></td>
         </tr>';
    }
?>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function idna1(el){
      var rownumber = $(el).closest('td').index();
      alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[rownumber].cells[3].textContent);
    }
  </script>
```

if i refresh page(every page) then both table works absolately fine.but i just change my url every time and refresh only my body tag (where this code used).

Comment: They both have id "myTable" - are they on the same page?

Comment: no differnt page...........

Comment: if i change the table name,they are still not working...........

Comment: It's not clear what this means *"refresh only my body tag"* - is this an SPA?

Comment: means,every time when i redirect to another page with <a> tag, i just change the URL and load the other page body,without body the other tag are same.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I guess both these bits of html code can appear in the same HTML document?

If so, you are defining the js function called `idna1()` twice. You may want to change its name to, i dunno, `idna2()`, in one of your tables.